# EF 6 - Error 3025 - Table-per-Hierarchy Key Fragmentation

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm trying out EF and getting an error I don't quite understand. I have a DB table that has 5 columns. SearchChannelID (int), SearchProductID (int), SearchKeywordID (int), SearchTypeID(int), TermToFind (nvarchar(50)). The first 4 form a primary key. Table is called SearchCriteria.

After creating my model in VS (EF6) I create 2 new entities - OragnicScrapeCriteria and PScrapeCriteria based off SearchCriteria.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcwt5grg8laol10/Screenshot%202014-08-14%2015.40.00.png

```
Error   1   Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 507:Must specify mapping for all key properties (SearchCriteria.SearchChannelID, SearchCriteria.SearchProductID, SearchCriteria.SearchKeywordID, SearchCriteria.SearchTypeID) of table SearchCriteria.
D:\Projects\Charon\Charon\CharonDataAccess\CharonModel.edmx 508 513 CharonDataAccess

 Error  2   Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 515:Must specify mapping for all key properties (SearchCriteria.SearchChannelID, SearchCriteria.SearchProductID, SearchCriteria.SearchKeywordID, SearchCriteria.SearchTypeID) of table SearchCriteria.
D:\Projects\Charon\Charon\CharonDataAccess\CharonModel.edmx 516 521 CharonDataAccess
```

Then I remove the discriminator (SearchTypeID) from the base entity. Did my table mappings to set the Discriminator 'Maps to SearchCriteria' as appropriate for each derived entity.

Is this because SearchTypeID is part of the primary key and it is fragmented between 2 derived entities, if so, what are my options?

Thanks,

Michael